# AngularJS datables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS. I am facing a problem, my data is not being displayed in data table. Can anyone help me with this?

my code

HTML code

```
<div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-hover" datatable="">
    <thead>
        <th>Account ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Registered On</th>
        <!--<th>Settings</th>-->
        <th>Status</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td style="text-align:left;">{{user.account}}</td>
            <td style="text-align:left;">{{user.name}}</td>
            <td style="text-align:left;">{{user.email}}</td>

            <td style="text-align:left;" ng-model="dateVal">{{user.register}}</td>

            <td style="text-align:left;">

                <span class="label {{ user.status == 1 && 'label-success' || 'label-danger'}} " ng-click="updated(user.id)">
                                             {{ user.status == 1 && 'Active' || 'Inactive'}}
                                            </span>

            </td>

            <td>
                <a href="index.html#/edit_userpermission?id={{user.id}}" class="fa fa-cog" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS code

```
 /* User Listing */
  var url = UserService.url+'users.php?token='+localStorage.getItem("token");

  $http.get(url).success( function(data) 
  {

     $('#myTable').DataTable();

     if(data.login != null ){
       $location.path( "/logout" );      
     }
     $scope.users = data;

  });
```

am getting an output as...
[image: Output]

When I click the sort option it displays "no data available in table"...
Why do this happen?
Waiting for a response. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use filters for sorting purpose

Comment: i referred the site " https://datatables.net/ " . I included two files are available on the DataTables CDN:

Comment: Can you provide a working plunker?

Answer (score 1):

take care.

0- You must define the datatable as ng. So, in your line:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-hover" datatable="">
```

You must change it to:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-hover" datatable="ng">
```

1- Take care about the numbers of data in each row. Because if is different number of. It will give you some problems.

2- Are you using the angular datatables? You must used with the jquery datatables. With both it will work.

You can check the this Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0lDhg9Mehn72E3rWAsLN?p=preview

Plus, you can check the documentation here: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay

Comment: still i am not getting the output correctly. When  i use "datatable" in my script, it does not display any thing. and it shows error......

Comment: Did you check the plunkr? Did you add the datatable="ng"? Is another error or is the same? If it shows a new error can you share it?

Comment: error 1: Uncaught Error: No module: datatables    in angular.min.js

Comment: Are you importing `angular datatables`??? You must add it in your index.html: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-datatables/0.5.4/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>` and your app must include it in your app.js `angular.module('myApp', ['datatables']);`